# JointJs graph inside a modal bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jointjs

I use JointJs with a graph and a joint.dia.Paper

I use this graph in many views in my website.

```html
      var graph = new joint.dia.Graph();

      // define page to draw in
      var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
        el: $('#graphDefault'),
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        gridSize: 10,
        model: graph,
        interactive: false,
      });
```

My graph is correct in the native
 page, but if i want to use it in a model bootstrap box,
 the view is incorrect, there is a scale by default.

Rectangles are too big, a scale factor of (100, 70) is on all of them.

How to disable the scale inside the modal box content ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set the content to visible in the DOM content, if not, the graph can't render correctly.